# Placing a crypto order with Robinhood nummus API

Tags: python, api, python-requests, cryptocurrency

I am trying to extend [this repo](https://github.com/LichAmnesia/Robinhood) with support for cryptocurrency trading using Python (will create a PR once completed).

I have all the API methods working with the exception of actually placing trades.

The endpoint for placing crypto orders is `https://nummus.robinhood.com/orders/`

This endpoint expects a `POST` request to be made with the body in JSON format along with the following headers:

```
"Accept": "application/json",
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
"Accept-Language": "en;q=1, fr;q=0.9, de;q=0.8, ja;q=0.7, nl;q=0.6, it;q=0.5",
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"X-Robinhood-API-Version": "1.0.0",
"Connection": "keep-alive",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36",
"Origin": "https://robinhood.com",
"Authorization": "Bearer <access_token>"
```

The payload I'm sending looks like this:

```
{   
    'account_id': <account id>,
    'currency_pair_id': '3d961844-d360-45fc-989b-f6fca761d511', // this is BTC
    'price': <BTC price derived using quotes API>,
    'quantity': <BTC quantity>,
    'ref_id': str(uuid.uuid4()), // Im not sure why this is needed but I saw someone else use [the uuid library][2] to derive this value like this
    'side': 'buy',
    'time_in_force': 'gtc',
    'type': 'market'
}
```

The response I get is as follows:
`400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://nummus.robinhood.com/orders/`

I can confirm that I am able to authenticate successfully since I am able to use the `https://nummus.robinhood.com/accounts/` and `https://nummus.robinhood.com/holdings/` endpoints to view my account data and holdings.

I also believe that my `access_token` in the Authentication header is correct because if I set it to some random value (`Bearer abc123`, for instance) I get a `401 Client Error: Unauthorized` response.

I think the issue has to do with the payload but I am not able to find good documentation for the `nummus.robinhood.com` API.

Does anyone see how/whether my request payload is malformed and/or can point me in the right direction to documentation for the `nummus.robinhood.com/orders` endpoint?

Comment: Try sending in the request payload as `s = requests.Session();res=s.request("post", url, json=json_payload, timeout=10)` than sending payload via `data` parameter in the requests library

Comment: I used the requests.post method, but sending as json rather than data worked! thank you. please reply this as an answer and I will award you the bounty

Comment: Posted as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the json payload as the value to the parameter `json` in the requests post call

```
import requests

json_payload = {   
    'account_id': <account id>,
    'currency_pair_id': '3d961844-d360-45fc-989b-f6fca761d511', // this is BTC
    'price': <BTC price derived using quotes API>,
    'quantity': <BTC quantity>,
    'ref_id': str(uuid.uuid4()), // Im not sure why this is needed but I saw someone else use [the uuid library][2] to derive this value like this
    'side': 'buy',
    'time_in_force': 'gtc',
    'type': 'market'
}

headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Accept-Language": "en;q=1, fr;q=0.9, de;q=0.8, ja;q=0.7, nl;q=0.6, it;q=0.5",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "X-Robinhood-API-Version": "1.0.0",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36",
    "Origin": "https://robinhood.com",
    "Authorization": "Bearer <access_token>"
}

url = "https://nummus.robinhood.com/orders/"

s = requests.Session()
res = s.request("post", url, json=json_payload, timeout=10, headers=headers)
print(res.status_code)
print(res.text)
```